# How to subscribe a wxPython phoenix TreeListCtrl to mouse double-clicks

Tags: double-click, subscribe, wxpython

Using wxPython4 (a.k.a. phoenix), I want a gui with a TreeListCtrl to subscribe to double-clicks and tell the handler code what cell in the TreeListCtrl was double-clicked.

The specific version of wxPython4 that I'm currently using is 4.0.0b2, which comes with a demo code package available here: https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/4.0.0b2/ , and which includes the code below for TreeListCtrl demonstration.

How should I modify this code so that I can handle double clicks on the TreeListCtrl?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx
import wx.dataview

import images

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        self.log = log
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)

        self.tree = wx.dataview.TreeListCtrl(self, -1, style =
                                        wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE
                                        #| wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS
                                        #| wx.TR_TWIST_BUTTONS
                                        #| wx.TR_ROW_LINES
                                        #| wx.TR_COLUMN_LINES
                                        #| wx.TR_NO_LINES
                                        | wx.TR_FULL_ROW_HIGHLIGHT
                                   )

        isz = (16,16)
        il = wx.ImageList(isz[0], isz[1])
        fldridx     = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_FOLDER,      wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        fldropenidx = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_FILE_OPEN,   wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        fileidx     = il.Add(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_NORMAL_FILE, wx.ART_OTHER, isz))
        smileidx    = il.Add(images.Smiles.GetBitmap())

        self.tree.SetImageList(il)
        self.il = il

        # create some columns
        self.tree.AppendColumn("Main column")
        self.tree.AppendColumn("Column 1")
        self.tree.AppendColumn("Column 2")
        ##self.tree.SetMainColumn(0) # the one with the tree in it...
        self.tree.SetColumnWidth(0, 175)

        self.root = self.tree.InsertItem(self.tree.GetRootItem(), wx.dataview.TLI_FIRST, "The Root Item")

        self.tree.SetItemText(self.root, 1, "col 1 root")
        self.tree.SetItemText(self.root, 2, "col 2 root")
        self.tree.SetItemImage(self.root, closed=fldridx, opened=fldropenidx)


        for x in range(15):
            txt = "Item %d" % x
            child = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, txt)
            self.tree.SetItemText(child, 1, txt + "(c1)")
            self.tree.SetItemText(child, 2, txt + "(c2)")
            self.tree.SetItemImage(child, closed=fldridx, opened=fldropenidx)

            for y in range(5):
                txt = "item %d-%s" % (x, chr(ord("a")+y))
                last = self.tree.AppendItem(child, txt)
                self.tree.SetItemText(last, 1, txt + "(c1)")
                self.tree.SetItemText(last, 2, txt + "(c2)")
                self.tree.SetItemImage(last, closed=fldridx, opened=fldropenidx)

                for z in range(5):
                    txt = "item %d-%s-%d" % (x, chr(ord("a")+y), z)
                    item = self.tree.AppendItem(last,  txt)
                    self.tree.SetItemText(item, 1, txt + "(c1)")
                    self.tree.SetItemText(item, 2, txt + "(c2)")
                    #TODO: Phoenix change selected to smiley
                    self.tree.SetItemImage(item, closed=fileidx, opened=smileidx)
                    ## self.tree.SetItemImage(item, fileidx, which = wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
                    ## self.tree.SetItemImage(item, smileidx, which = wx.TreeItemIcon_Selected)


        self.tree.Expand(self.root)

        ## self.tree.GetMainWindow().Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_UP, self.OnRightUp)
        self.tree.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnActivate)


    def OnActivate(self, event):
        self.log.write('OnActivate: %s' % self.tree.GetItemText(event.GetItem()))

    def OnRightUp(self, event):
        pos = event.GetPosition()
        item, flags, col = self.tree.HitTest(pos)
        if item:
            self.log.write('Flags: %s, Col:%s, Text: %s' %
                           (flags, col, self.tree.GetItemText(item, col)))

    def OnSize(self, event):
        self.tree.SetSize(self.GetSize())
```

I tried the following two variants at the end of the Panel constructor, neither of which works:

Variant 1:

```
...
    self.tree.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnActivate)
    self.tree.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnLeftDClick)

def OnLeftDClick(self, event):
    print("LeftDClick")

def OnActivate(self, event):
...
```

Variant 2:

```
...
    self.tree.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnActivate)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnLeftDClick)

def OnLeftDClick(self, event):
    print("LeftDClick")

def OnActivate(self, event):
...
```

I would have hoped to see the "LeftDClick" text appear on the console when I double-click somewhere in the tree, but it doesn't.

Note 1: I used to have that functionality working in wxPython3, by subscribing as follows:

```
self.tree.GetMainWindow().Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnLeftDClick)
```

That code doesn't work any more in wxPython4:

```
AttributeError: 'TreeListCtrl' object has no attribute 'GetMainWindow'
```

Note 2: The reason I want to specifically make this work for wxPython4 is that I'm porting from python2 to python3, and wxPython3 is incompatible with python3.

Note 3: The wxPython4.0.0b2 TreeListCtrl comes with the following bug in the C++ code: http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/17476 . The patch attached to that bug filing solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a workaround for my problem: wxPython provides a class called HyperTreeList, which is very similar to the wxPython3 TreeListCtrl, and which seems to have undergone less changes between wxPython3 and wxPython4.

https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.hypertreelist.HyperTreeList.html

In particular it accepts the subscription to double-clicks in the traditional manner:

```
self.tree.GetMainWindow().Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnLeftDClick)
```

Only two changes needed to be made in my case when switching from TreeListCtrl to HyperTreeList wx3:

1. `tree.SetBackgroundColour('white')`
2. `tree.SetImageList became tree.AssignImageList`

Answer (score 0):

self.tree.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnActivate) -> self.tree.Bind(wx.dataview.EVT_TREELIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.OnActivate) 
This one can work for my case.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.